# Can I use Entity SQL to query an IQueryable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-sql

I know I can use ESQL to query an `ObjectSet of T` but can I use it to query an arbitrary `IQueryable of T`?

**EDIT**

Example:

```
var originalQuery = from t in Transactions where t.Date < DateTime.Now select t;

// query is now an IQueryable<Transation>. Now I want to do some dynamic manipulations
// on originalQuery by using ESQL

var manipulationQuery = "select t.a as A from T as t";

// I want to execute manipulationQuery over the originalQuery, something like this:
// (this is a hipotetical method. It does not exist)
var transactions = context.RunESQLOverIQueryable(originalQuery, manipulationQuery).ToList();
```

**EDIT 2**

Actually the use case is the following: I need a programmer to code a method that returns an IQueryable(T) representing the core query. This query will be given to a ReportControl that must execute a series of group bys on this query, as well as selecting which columns must be retrieved and so forth. I thought that manipulating the core query dynamically through ESQL is a good choice. I'm not sure either.

Comment: Sorry, can't think - what's Entity SQL in this context? If you're using EF then most IQueryable<T>s you get can be cast back to ObjectQuery<T>s and you can then use the methods again.

Comment: OK, thanks - so there's a non-hypothetical method that does the same thing over an ObjectQuery? (Do [EntityCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343124.aspx)s do that?)

Comment: @Rup: Thank you for your reply. I don't think this string predicate Where method helps me solving my problem. I have once again edited the question with additional informations. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) library. It is part of [samples for Visual studio 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx) but it will work with 2010 as well.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer the core question, it solves my problem. Thank you